# jquery dialog not popping up when called from appended button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a working dialog popup that opens when a user clicks on a button with the id 'create-user' (at the bottom of this snippet):

```
<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label>Form Owners</label>
    </div>
    <table style="width: 40%; border: 1px solid #dddddd; border-collapse: collapse;" id="users" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; " class="ui-widget-header ">
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<br />
<button id="create-user">Add Owner</button>
```

I am trying to open the same dialog when a user clicks the delete button within a row in the above table, which is not present at the initial load of the page, but is appended after the user adds a name to the table:

```
    function addUser() {
        var valid = true;
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

        $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
            "<td>" + name.val() + "<button id='create-user' style='float:right' title='Delete' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs actionbutton'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button>" + "</td>" +
            "</tr>" );
        $("#owners").val($('#owners').val() + name.val() + ";");
        dialog.dialog("close");
    }
```

As you can see in the line

```
"<td>" + name.val() + "<button id='create-user' style='float:right'
```

I assign the same id 'create-user' as I do in the table, which should call the same addUser function and open the dialog, but it's not working.

~~~UPDATE~~~

I have added this function, which I think is the 'binding click event' people have suggested:

```
    $("#create-user2").button().on("click", function () {
        dialog.dialog("open");
    });
```

and have changed the id to create-user2 above and when the button is created:

```
"<button id='create-user2' style='float:right'...
```

But it is still not working

Comment: after you append tr, bind click event to the button

Comment: 1. You should avoid using the same id on different elements. 2. You have to attach the event listener to the newly created element

Comment: Use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) for dynamically created elements.

Comment: can you show your code, where you have attached event listener to the button

Comment: Post a jsfiddle with your latest code so we a full picture to look at.

Answer (score 1):

You need to not have the same id used for multiple elements.  You also need to bind the click handler after adding dom element to the page.

You can use a delegated event handler which binds the event listener to an element higher up in the DOM hierarchy which is listening to all events fired by its children.

e.g.

```
<div id="outerElement">
  <button class="btn">First</button>
  <button class="btn">Second</button>
</div>

$('#outerElement').on('click', '.btn', function(e){
  console.log(e.target);
})
```

In this example you can continually add button elements in the `.outerElement` div without having to update your event handler.

Comment: This is likely the issue. I have definitely had problems with duplicate IDs in the past.  Change the ID to a Class and see what happens

Comment: @carter I changed the id to 'create-user2' as you can see in my update, but am not sure if i binded the click handler correctly (I got that solution from the JQuery API)

Answer (score 0):

The same id on the newly added button will allow it to open the same dialog (and of course [it must be unique in a document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)).

You need to [attach an event handler](https://api.jquery.com/on/) like:

```
var tblRow = $("<tr>" +
             "<td>" + name.val() + "<button id='create-user2' style='float:right' title='Delete' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs actionbutton'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button>" + "</td>" +
             "</tr>");

tblRow.find('button#create-user2').button().on('click', function() {
    dialog.dialog("open"); // where dialog is instance of jq dialog, dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({...})
});

$( "#users tbody" ).append(tblRow);
```